# Emptying PHP Session variables via javascript/jquery before Link direct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following issue:
I have several variables stored in php session variables. Now, if I click on a link, I want to to set all values of variable1, variable2 and variable3 to empty before that link directs the user to the linked page. 
How can I make sure, the variables are set to empty before that testpage.php is loaded? Any way to be 100% safe?

```
<?
$_SESSION["variable1"] = "value1";
$_SESSION["variable2"] = "value2";
$_SESSION["variable3"] = "value3";
?>
<a href="testpage.php" id="killswitch">Go to but kill sessions before loading page</a>

<script>
$(function(){
            $(document.body).on('click touchstart', '#killswitch', function(){
                <?
$_SESSION["variable1"] = "";
$_SESSION["variable2"] = "";
$_SESSION["variable3"] = "";
?>
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You can do an ajax request to end the sessions then after a successful call back you can redirect the user to any link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would be the easiest way to make an ajax request to the server, which modifies the session variables.

So you need a simple script on server side which does this and an `$.ajax` call in jQuery, within your event. First you should prevent the link from being called, because first we fire the ajax request. And in callback of this request, we call the href of the link.

It could look like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click touchstart', '#killswitch', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "killswitch.php"
  }).done(function() {
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.